# Is it possible to stop the screen going off, when plugged to mains/PC?

Tags: functionality

I have a bunch of live tiles that are handy to glance at to tell me what meetings to go to - this is great, but when my phone is on my desk on charge, but it doesn't seem possible to set a different time out when on mains (or plugged into a PC) versus when it's running on battery?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, and you can do this in `Settings > lock + wallpaper > Screen times out after`. But not all phones supports this action. I know Nokia Lumia 800 have max time out limit of 5 minutes. Also remember this action is not specific when charging.

See how in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ky6Z8eSgC5k).

Comment: This isn't what Rowland was asking.

Comment: This only lets you set a single global setting, not have different settings for on power/on battery